# Formatting Table visualization in Report View

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to PowerBI and I have just started learning it. I have created new calendar table.

```
Dates = 
CALENDAR(
    DATE( YEAR((MIN(Sales[Order Date]))), 1, 1 ),
    DATE( YEAR((MAX(Sales[Order Date]))), 12, 31 )
    )
```

In `Report View` I am using `Table` visualization and it looks like this where year is repeated for every month.

[image]

I want the report should display year only once. like this
[image]

Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your table to a matrix and add fields as follows:

[image]

[image]

Expand all the values. Turn off stepped layout.

[image]

Turn off the +/- icons.

[image]

Final result.

[image]